# Using map function to map to user options to specific function

Tags: c++, pointers

I am new to C++ and need some help with the following:

If i have no namespace this works fine as soon as i have this i get a error :

```
(active) E0109 expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-)
```

I am attaching a solution where i have implemented this code to show the error.

What i am tryng to achive is to use this map to call my menu options a user can select, it has a header file as well as the cpp implemtation file in it.

I have attached the source code with the error showing when trying to compile this.

I would greatly appreciate some help - sample attached done in visual studio [Sample Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j5nkxabjah313wz/SampleMenu.zip?dl=0)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j5nkxabjah313wz/SampleMenu.zip?dl=0

Comment: Provide relevant code here. Link should just be a "bonus".

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Please also copy errors from the compiler output rather than the visual studio error list as that usually contains more details